# postgresql multiple functions transaction control

Tags: postgresql, function, transactions, procedure

I have created 4 postgresql mock up functions, to test transaction controls with multiple functions, as below,

```
create table test
(
    text varchar(20)
);

create table log
(
    text varchar(20)
);

create or replace function test1
(
    p_data       in text,
    p_result     out text
)
as $$
begin

    insert into test (text)
    values(1);   

    p_result := '';                

exception
        when others then

          PERFORM log_entry
                (
                  'test1 error'
                );         
                
          p_result := '';  

end
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

create or replace function test2
(
    p_data       in text,
    p_result     out text
)
as $$
begin

    insert into test (text)
    values(2);

    p_result := '';   

exception
        when others then
            
            PERFORM log_entry
                (
                  'test2 error'
                );
          
            p_result := '';     
           
end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

create or replace function test3
(
    p_data       in text,
    p_result     out text
)
as $$
begin

    insert into test (text)
    values(3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333);

    p_result := ''; 

exception
        when others then

            PERFORM log_entry
                (
                  'test3 error'
                );
            
            p_result := '';  
end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

create or replace function log_entry
(
    p_data       in text
)
returns void as $$
 
begin


    insert into log (text)
    values(p_data);

end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The way I am calling the functions are,

```
DO $$ BEGIN

    PERFORM "test1"('');
    PERFORM "test2"('');
    PERFORM "test3"('');

END $$;
```

So when function "test3" gets executed, and fails due to the data it is trying to insert into test table is too long, I can see table test has 2 rows, value 1 and 2; and table log has 1 row, value test3 error.

My question is,

if what I want to achieve is, roll back transactions that was done by function test1 and test2, but only commit the log entry (meaning table test should be empty, and table log should have 1 row being test3 error), how to do that?

Note: I don't want to combine 3 functions into 1, as in real case, the parameter inputs would be too many, almost 100 inputs, the function signature gets too large, and I don't want to use dblink either.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There is no one-line modification to achieve that. You'll have to redesign your code.

One possibility is to add another output parameter to the functions that contains the log message. Then the code could be like this:

```
DO
$$DECLARE
   result text;
   errmsg text;
BEGIN
   SELECT test1(NULL) INTO result, errmsg;
   IF errmsg IS NOT NULL THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION '%', errmsg;
   END IF;

   SELECT test2(NULL) INTO result, errmsg;
   IF errmsg IS NOT NULL THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION '%', errmsg;
   END IF;

   SELECT test2(NULL) INTO result, errmsg;
   IF errmsg IS NOT NULL THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION '%', errmsg;
   END IF;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN raise_exception THEN
      GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS errmsg := MESSAGE_TEXT;
      PERFORM log_entry(errmsg);
END;$$;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I should have made it clear in my original post. I need to expose those 3 functions (in real world could be 10 of them), to a client ( an API caller) to invoke, that is why I am trying to decouple the functions into smaller ones instead of one single function with huge signature.  Any suggestion what the best way to achieve that? Thank you.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, but you will have to change your API.